# Custom react hook to fetch data is not giving data on second hit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a below custom `useEffect` hook to fetch data from API.

```
export const useGetData = (url, body, isNew) => {
const [state, setState] = useState([]);
const [error, setError] = useState({});

useEffect(() => {
    if (isNew) {
        fetch(url, {
            method: 'Post',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(body)
        }).then(response => response.json())
            .then(apiData => {
                   setState({ apiData });
            }).catch(error =>
                console.error('Error:', error)
            );
        setError(error);
        console.log("Error: " + error);
        return error;
    }
}, []);
return state;
}
```

Now, in my component i am trying to use above hook after a `handleInputChanges` event as below

```
let dt = {};
const [inputParam, setInputParam] = useState({
    FirstName: 'Tom',
    LastName : 'Harris'
});

const handleInputChanges = (params) =>{
    setInputParam(params);
};

dt = useGetData (url, inputParam, true);
```

With above code, i am able to hit `useGetData` custom hook but, hook is not calling the API url and hence data `dt` is not updating. What's wrong? Kindly suggest.

Comment: If you want to run an effect and clean it up only once (on mount and unmount), you can pass an empty array ([]) as a second argument. This tells React that your effect doesn’t depend on any values from props or state, so it never needs to re-run. So just check if you need to pass an empty array.

Comment: @Mukund i passed `([])`, please see my code

Comment: What is the usage of  isNew in your custom hook? Do you just want to make a post request if isNew is true?

Comment: sorry i mean to say you will not required to pass array if you want to re-run. So remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not passing 2nd argument properly inside the useEffect.

Make it like this

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (isNew) {
        fetch(url, {
            method: 'Post',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(body)
        }).then(response => response.json())
            .then(apiData => {
                   setState({ apiData });
            }).catch(error =>
                console.error('Error:', error)
                setError(error); // Save your error inside the catch block
            );

        // return error; <-- Do not return anything that isn't used for useEffect cleanup! Use return only for cleanup, like unsubscribing API. 
    }
}, [isNew]); <--- This will ensure that everytime isNew changes, it will run the useEffect again.
```

But you might wanna change the dependency to other variable, as isNew is a boolean, therefore i think it might not work if on the next call, you're passing true again.

You can use the URL as a dependency to the useEffect, so that on every new URL, it will run the call inside useEffect.

Comment: I need to add `body` as dependency because that's what will get changed from event..but adding that gives me `Uncaught TypeError: destroy is not a function
    at commitHookEffectList (react-dom.development.js:22012)` error..What's and why that error is coming

Comment: @Lara you're returning something inside the useEffect hook. Return in useEffect is used for cleanup, and it has to be a function. But you're returning error instead, which caused it to throw error like that. I clean up my answer above for your reference.

Answer (score 1):

You are using empty array in second parameter of useEffect this won't update when props change. This is similar to componentDidMount.
You need to either pass on the props like [url, body, isNew] or dont pass second parameter in useEffect at all.

```
export const useGetData = (url, body, isNew) => {
const [state, setState] = useState([]);
const [error, setError] = useState({});

useEffect(() => {
    if (isNew) {
        fetch(url, {
            method: 'Post',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(body)
        }).then(response => response.json())
            .then(apiData => {
                   setState({ apiData });
            }).catch(error =>
                console.error('Error:', error)
            );
        setError(error);
        console.log("Error: " + error);
        return error;
    }
}, [url, body, isNew]);
return state;
}
```